# What speed did the (interstellar) comet C/2017 U1 PANSTARRS have at perihelion?

Tags: comet, escape-velocity

[C/2017 U1 PANSTARRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/2017_U1) is a comet with an eccentricity of close to 1.2, so it is a strong candidate for having interstellar origin. It's perihelion was at 0.25 AU.

What speed did it have relative to the Sun when it swung around it at the closest?

Comment: https://twitter.com/AscendingNode/status/923223634386206720

Comment: @Erik Gaah! Aren't astronomers getting very media trigger happy? Don't they talk about these things with each other internally before they publish? Or do they, but lie in order to set up each other? Eccentricity of 0.18-0.19 looked super high. But the error bar was apparently so large that it couldn't fit inside of the telescope, it seems.

Comment: FWIW there has been significant pushback on that AscendingNode tweet.

Comment: https://youtu.be/0GPqb-bXhjg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking `q = 0.2531011` AU (perihelion radius) and `e = 1.1937160` from the [latest ephemeris for A/2017 U1](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/mpec/K17/K17UI5.html), we get a semimajor axis of $$a = \frac{r_p}{1-e} = -1.3065575~\textrm{AU}.$$ Using the definitions of 1 AU and $\mu_{\textrm{Sun}}$ from [here](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?constants), we get the heliocentric velocity at perihelion of $$v_p = \sqrt{\mu_{\textrm{Sun}}\left(\frac{2}{r_p} - \frac{1}{a}\right)} = \boxed{87.6872~\frac{\textrm{km}}{\textrm{s}}}$$ (assuming I did my math right). This is subject to change as the orbit gets refined with further observations.